# Hibernate - Deserialization of ENUM field not working

Tags: java, hibernate, enums, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I have user entity containing enum field as follow

```
public class User implements Serializable {
    protected String email;
    protected String name;
    protected RoleType roleType;
    
    public enum RoleType implements Serializable {
        NORMAL("Normal"),
        ADMIN("Admin"),

        RoleType(){}
        private String type;
        private RoleType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }
        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class UserEntity extends User{
    public UserEntity() {
        super();
    }
    public UserEntity(User user) {
        super(user);
    }
    //Getter and Setter for all the overridden fields
}
```

While executing this criteria API I am getting user records with all the details but RoleType coming as null.

```
Criteria c = session().createCriteria(UserEntity.class);
c.add(Restrictions.eq("email",email));
User user = (User) c.uniqueResult();
return user;
```

Comment: You *have to* use `@Enumerated` in jpa on enum types  (on getter/setter!??) .. https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-an-enum-type-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: Side question: what’s the point of declaring an unused constructor `RoleType(){}` in an `enum` type?